# Installing Windows to Mac External Drive - WinToUSB Problem

Tags: mac, hard-drive, windows, bootcamp, youtube

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IhW722IMwE) tutorial on YouTube (*How to install Windows 10 "Boot Camp" on a Mac External Drive the EASY way! (2020 edition)*), up to the part where I had to use WintoUSB to install Windows on my external drive (I'm using a Seagate One Touch SSD).

I downloaded WinToUSB version 7.5, which is a different version than the one used in the video.

[image: WinToUSB version 7.5]

I chose the middle option (Windows Installation USB) to download Windows into my external drive, and the process was similar to the video's so I thought there was no harm done here.

However, I ended up with two WinToUSB drives with different contents.

[image: Two WinToUSB drives]

**Contents in "WinToUSB"**
[image: Contents in "WinToUSB"]

**Contents in "WINTOUSB"**
[image: Contents in "WINTOUSB"]

**This is what it looks like on my Windows screen.**

[image: This is what it looks like on my Windows screen.]

Obviously I screwed up somewhere, but I would like to know if anyone could help me undo what I have just done. I want to uninstall this version of WinToUSB, and download the version used in the tutorial. However, what should I do to the two WinToUSB's I accidentally created? Should I leave it as is and redo the process?

Comment: You only have one external drive. At 4:05 in the video, there are instructions on how to format (erase) this drive. I would repeat those instructions.